# How to use cursor() for pagination?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination, database-cursor

Can anyone point me to a practical application of `cursor()` to do pagination?

I am not clear how to use `cursor()` as given in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_cursor).

This is my query:

```
items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30")
```

which I render like this:

```
self.response.out.write("<ol>")
for item in items:
    self.response.out.write("""<li><a href="/vote/%s?type=%s"> ^ </a><a href="%s">%s</a> <span id='Small'>(%s)</span><br /> 
        <div id='Small'> 
        %s points %s by %s <a href="/item/%s"></a> | 
        <a href="/item/%s#disqus_thread"></a></div>
        </li><br /> """ % 
        (str(item.key().id()), merchandise_type, item.url, item.title, urlparse(item.url).netloc,
        item.points, item.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p"), item.user_who_liked_this_item, str(item.key().id()), str(item.key().id())))                               
                                        
   self.response.out.write("</ol>")
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Hi Amir: Thanks for your answer but I could't make this link work. Here's what I have:

```
#===========adding cursor here===========#
            cursor = self.request.get("cursor")
            if cursor: query.with_cursor(cursor)
            items = query.fetch(30)
            cursor  = query.cursor()
        
#===========adding cursor here===========#

#===========regular output===========#
            self.response.out.write("<ol>")
            for item in items:
                self.response.out.write("""<li>
                <a href="/vote/%s?type=%s"> ^ </a><a href="%s">
                <span id="large">%s</span></a> 
                <span id='Small'>(%s)</span>
                <br />  
                %s<br /> <span id='Small'> 
                %s points %s by %s <a href="/item/%s"></a> | 
                <a href="/item/%s#disqus_thread"></a>
                </span>
                </li><br /> """ %           
                (str(item.key().id()), merchandise_type, item.url, 
                item.title, urlparse(item.url).netloc, 
                item.summary, item.points, item.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p"), 
                item.user_who_liked_this_item, str(item.key().id()),  
                str(item.key().id())))                               
                                        
            self.response.out.write("</ol>")
#===========regular output===========#

#===========link to cursor===========#
            self.response.out.write("""<a href="/dir?type=%s?cursor=%s">Next
            Page</a>""" % (merchandise_type, cursor))
```

But this results in this url which displays nothing:

```
http://localhost:8083/dir?type=newest?cursor=E9oBdgoTc2FyYWgtZm9yLXByZXNpZGVudBoESXRlbUtSBGRhdGVYAkwhQ1VSU09SIWoiahNzYXJhaC1mb3ItcHJlc2lkZW50cgsLEgRJdGVtGKsCDHIVCAcaBGRhdGUgACoJCMid8OXW4qYCggELCxIESXRlbRirAgzgAQAU
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started...

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY date DESC")
cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
if cursor: query.with_cursor(cursor)
items = query.fetch(30)
cursor = query.cursor()

... your regular output ...

self.response.out.write('<a href="yoururl?cursor=%s">Next Page</a>' % cursor)
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to make the 'Previous Page' link? :D

Comment: The easiest way is to simple use the back button.  Since cursor is part of the url, the url will tell the query where to start.  If you are doing some sort of Ajax solution, you can store the previous cursors. There is more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752931/pagination-techniques-using-google-app-engine

Comment: thanks for your answer but I could not make the link to next page to work. What am I doing wrong? I added an update with the code. Thanks again.

Comment: The second ? should be an & in the url